# Why is my C program not printing anything sometimes from the string inconsistantly? (using linked lists)

Tags: c

I'm trying to use linked lists to store the data from the periodic table. Name, symbol and atomic weight. My code is printing correctly for some elements and but the element name is disappearing sometimes. running the same code multiple times, it's not printing different names at different times. (I messed up the order while giving the inputs, but please ignore that.)

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct list{char element[20]; char sym[20];float weight;struct list*next;}list;


int printlist(list *h, char *title){
    printf("%s\n", title);
    while(h!=NULL){
        printf("%s: %s: %f \n", h->element, h->sym, h->weight);
        h = h-> next;   
    }
}

list* create_list(char e[], char s[], float w){
    list * head = malloc(sizeof(list));
    strcpy(head->element,e);
    strcpy(head -> sym,s);
    head -> weight = w;
    head -> next = NULL;
    return head;
}

void add_to_rear(char e[], char s[], float w, list*h){
    while(h->next != NULL){
        h= h-> next;
    }
    list *nn = create_list(e, s, w);
    h -> next = nn;
}

int main(){

    list list_of_atoms;
    list * head = NULL;
    for(int i=0; i<1;i++){
        printf("element %d", i+1);
        char el[20];
        char symbol[2];
        float atwt;
        scanf("%s", el);
        scanf("%s", symbol);
        scanf("%f", &atwt);
        head = create_list(el, symbol, atwt);
    }
    for(int i=1; i<10;i++){
        printf("element %d", i+1);
        char el[20];
        char symbol[2];
        float atwt;
        scanf("%s", el);
        scanf("%s", symbol);
        scanf("%f", &atwt);
        add_to_rear(el, symbol, atwt, head);
    }
    printlist(head, "First 10 elements");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please do not post text as an image. Paste the text directly into the question.

Comment: `char symbol[2];`  You need 2 chars + '\0'.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Probably **3** chars + the `nul`: The IUPAC symbol for element #120 is Ubn (for the time being, at least).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes but that's no what's causing the problem. And Adrian I'm only dealing with the first 10 elements so I don't need more than 2 char.  Also, can you explain why would I need the null?

Comment: It's almost certainly what's causing the problem! You **must** allow space for the nul terminator in all C strings. "He" requires at least a 3-char array. As it stands, you are writing out-of-bounds in your array and triggering undefined behaviour.

Comment: In C strings are actually nul-terminated character arrays. If it doesn't contain a 0 byte it is not a string and you are not allowed to pass it to any function that expects a string or a buffer for a string.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yeah that fixed error. I'm currently learning C on Coursera. Where do I learn all these topics?

Comment: You learn from a *good* book/course/tutorial.

Comment: "that's no what's causing the problem" -- if you know all the answers then why ask? "why would I need the null?" -- because you're reading the symbols with `scanf` and copying them with `strcpy`, both of which work with NUL-terminated strings.

Comment: "Where do I learn all these topics?" -- For one, you should read the documentation of the functions you are using. From https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html "s      Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next
              pointer must be a pointer to the initial element of a
              character array that is long enough to hold the input
              sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0')," and ...

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html "The strcpy() function copies the string pointed to by src,
       including the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer pointed
       to by dest.  The strings may not overlap, and the destination
       string dest must be large enough to receive the copy.  Beware of
       buffer overruns!  (See BUGS.)"

Comment: Please do Not post Pictures-of-Text, instead copy/paste the text into your questions with `\`\`\`` on the line above and below the text to format as fixed-width. You picture of text consumes *24,155 bytes of storage* for what would be about 150 bytes of text (it adds up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allocate and fill in a bunch of `list`s (which is a misnomer; each struct is actually info about an element) and then discard them ... `head` ends up pointing to the last element entered, and its `next` field is `NULL`. You then read in all the elements again (why?), scanning each time to the end of the list and appending the element--which is an O(N*N) operation. (I suspect that you actually entered an empty list for the first loop, and then entered your 10 elements for the second loop, but it's impossible to tell because you provided the input as a truncated screen shot. Please don't do that. Instead, copy the text from your CMD window.) Edit: Now I see that your first loop actually only runs one time. It's like you wrote it one way, then changed your mind and wrote it another way, but left the old code there.

The reason the output is wrong is that you are using `scanf` to read 2-character  symbols *plus a terminating NUL* into `symbol[2]`, which isn't big enough. This is undefined behavior, but what it is probably doing is overwriting the first byte of the element name with a NUL. Notice that all the elements with 2-letter symbols are missing the element name and the ones with 1-letter symbols are not.

Comment: I did that because I used malloc only in create_list function. I first initialized the list and then used create_list again in add_to_rear. I haven't scanned anything twice or haven't just left some old code there. And to address your comments on my post. I thought I know the answer and was also confused at the same time. If it isn't clear to you, I'm a newbie coder and yea I just kept tweaking the code long enough till it worked (gave me a partial output).

Comment: @NagaKarumuri There is clearly duplicated and pointless code there. "I just kept tweaking the code long enough till it worked (gave me a partial output)." -- as a highly experienced programmer, I strongly recommend against this approach.

Comment: @NagaKarumuri "to address your comments on my post. I thought I know the answer and was also confused at the same time" -- the point is that, as a newbie with virtually no understanding of C asking why something isn't working, you should not tell someone who explains why it isn't working that that's not the reason, since you don't know the reason and don't know enough to know whether they are wrong (and they weren't).